# Use Electron remote from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a file that contains a function that opens a file open dialog. I want to call that function from the app's menu. But when I use `require` to use the function from the file I get an error.

Code:

Main.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const { openFile } = require('./index.js');

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        icon: __dirname + 'src/styles/media/icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
        },
    });
    win.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    );
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Open File',
                    click() {
                        openFile();
                    },
                    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
                }
            ]
        }]);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

index.js:

```js
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

function openFile() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title: 'Open File',
        properties: ['openFile'],
    });
}

module.exports = {
    openFile,
};
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
        <title>Stonecutter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error:
[image: error]

When I do the same thing but without the `required` the code works fine:

```js
// index.js
// --------
// This code works
function openFile() {
    console.log('Open file');
}

module.exports = {
    openFile,
};

// Main.js is the same
```

Comment: One beautiful thing about JavaScript is you can often take an actual look at the code of many libraries, or even run in a debugger to see what things are at runtime.  In this case, a good look at the `electron` docs would be prudent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a remote inside the main process. This is what causes the problem. Remote is what you use from Renderer process (scripts required from a BrowserView). So you need to write two different openFile functions for main and renderer processes.

So when you require `index.js` from `main.js` this is what cause the error. You need determine where you are in the main process or in the renderer. Watch `open-file.js` below to see how to do it.

All together it should look like this:

**`main.js`**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const {openFile} = require('./open-file')

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        icon: __dirname + 'src/styles/media/icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
        },
    });
    win.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    );

  }

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow()
  var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
  {
      label: 'File',
      submenu: [
          {
              label: 'Open File',
              click() {
                  openFile();
              },
              accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O',
          }
      ]
  }]);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
})
```

**`index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
        <title>Stonecutter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="open-file">Open file</button>
      <script>
        const {openFile} = require('./open-file.js')

        document.querySelector('#open-file').addEventListener('click', () => openFile())
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`open-file.js`**

```js
const electron = require('electron');

// electron.remote for Renderer Process and electron for Main Process
const {dialog} = (electron.remote || electron)

function openFile() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title: 'Open File',
        properties: ['openFile'],
    });
}

module.exports = {
    openFile,
};
```

This examples works as you expect. File `open-file.js` is what you have in `index.js`.

This is so because Electron runs its parts in different processes: the first is the [Main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/glossary#main-process). It is where you're getting when running `electron main.js`. The second is a [Renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/glossary#renderer-process) is running in a separate os process. This is where you get calling `win.loadURL()` and it has slightly different API and set of libraries.

Comment: This solution executes `openFile()` immediately. How can I use it to execute `openFile()` from the menu?

Comment: This is another question. You can bind a listener to a button. Inside of index.html script do this: `document.querySelector('#open-file').addEventListener('click', () => openFile())`. Of cause  you need to add a button in the body element before calling this.

Comment: I updated the example. So as soon as I answered your question and solve the error issue, mark my answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I think you understood me incorrectlyץ While your solution works perfectly when pressing the button. I want to open the file when pressing a menu item ([Menu](https://imgur.com/uAjW049)) ([inside `click()`](https://imgur.com/p6GycEZ)), not from a button.

Comment: I've updated the answer: `remote.js` was renamed into `open-file-remote.js` and `open-file.js` was added. The last one is the same code but for the main process.

Comment: Well I've simplified example code and remove duplicated parts from it to make it easier to understand. Now open file contains code for main and webpage contexts.

Comment: Can I use jQuery with this method?

Comment: I'm not sure about jQuery itself. I think it should work in renderer process where DOM is presented.